# Should I call multiple addNavigationHelpers in nested react navigation?

Tags: react-native, react-redux, react-navigation

I'm following https://github.com/parkerdan/SampleNavigation to integrate redux with react-navigation.

I have a question: should I call `addNavigationHelpers` multiple times for nested navigators?

In the sample:

```
const routeConfiguration = {
    TabOneNavigation: { screen: TabOneNavigation },
    TabTwoNavigation: { screen: TabTwoNavigation },
    TabThreeNavigation: { screen: TabThreeNavigation },
    }

const tabBarConfiguration = {
    tabBarOptions:{
    activeTintColor: 'white',
    inactiveTintColor: 'blue', 
    activeBackgroundColor: 'blue', 
    inactiveBackgroundColor: 'white', 
    }
}
export const TabBar = TabNavigator(routeConfiguration,tabBarConfiguration);
```

`<TabBar
        navigation={
          addNavigationHelpers({
            dispatch: dispatch,
            state: navigationState,
          })
        }
      />`

`<NavigatorTabOne
        navigation={
          addNavigationHelpers({
            dispatch: dispatch,
            state: navigationState
          })
        }
      />`

`<NavigatorTabTwo
        navigation={
          addNavigationHelpers({
            dispatch: dispatch,
            state: navigationState
          })
        }
      />`

`<NavigatorTabThree
        navigation={addNavigationHelpers({
          dispatch: dispatch,
          state: navigationState
        })}
      />`

`addNavigationHelpers` is called 4 times, one for the TabNavigator and 3 others for the tabs.
Is this the recommended way by the document?

> Navigation state is automatically passed down from one navigator to another when you nest them.

Answer (score 0):

What actually are TabBar, NavigatorTabOne, NavigatorTabTwo... ?

I suppose you have some code like this:

```
export const TabBar = TabNavigator({
  NavigatorTabOne: { screen: NavigatorTabOne},
  NavigatorTabTwo: { screen: NavigatorTabTwo},
  NavigatorTabThree: { screen: NavigatorTabThree}
}, {
    initialRouteName: 'NavigatorTabOne',
  })
```

To create your root container you need this:

```
import { createReduxBoundAddListener, createReactNavigationReduxMiddleware } from 'react-navigation-redux-helpers';

export const navigationMiddleware = createReactNavigationReduxMiddleware(
  "root",
  state => state.nav,
);

const addListener = createReduxBoundAddListener("root");

class ReduxNavigation extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const { dispatch, nav } = this.props

    const navigation = ReactNavigation.addNavigationHelpers({
      dispatch,
      state: nav,
      addListener,
    });

    return <TabBar navigation={navigation} />
  }
}
```

This could be your reducer

```
const firstAction = TabBar.router.getActionForPathAndParams('NavigatorTabOne')
const initialState = TabBar.router.getStateForAction(firstAction)

export const reducer = (state = initialState, action) => {

  const nextState = TabBar.router.getStateForAction(action, state);

  return nextState || state;
};
```

Anyway, don't use that repository
[The official react navigation doc does exist](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/redux-integration.html)

If you want to use something for scaffolding your react native + redux + react navigation, you can have a look a [this project](https://github.com/infinitered/ignite), that will create app base in a command

Comment: I would love to follow the official doc and sample. but my problem is to use redux with nested react-navigation. I'm not sure what should I do for nested navigators. So the questions is: If I use nested navigators, should their `navigation`s be replaced by using  `addNavigationHelpers` as well?

Comment: The navigation prop is passed down to nested navigator, you don't need to propagate it manually. Just be sure you use your 'root' navigator (in this case TabBar) as root component in your app.  I'll expand my answer to show you how to